# Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket while executing docker stop

Tags: sockets, ubuntu, docker

I have 3 containers running on my docker, and I need to stop all of them using the following:

```
sudo docker stop $(docker ps -q)
```

When a run the command I got this message:

```
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.32/containers/json: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
See 'docker stop --help'.
Usage:  docker stop [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [CONTAINER...]
Stop one or more running containers
```

I made some search, and the cases that message show does not apply to my environment. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with Docker version 17.09.0-ce, build afdb6d4

What does this message mean?

Comment: docker post-installation steps: https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/#manage-docker-as-a-non-root-user

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
sudo usermod -a -G docker $USER
```

Reboot then run:

```
docker container run hello-world
```

it worked for me on ubuntu 18.2

Comment: No need to reboot `newgrp docker` should do it.

Answer (score 8):

If  you are getting "permission denied" that probably means you haven't added yourself in users group which can operate upon docker. To fix that, go to your terminal and type:

```
sudo usermod -aG docker <name-of-user-to-grant-permission>
```

The 'docker' parameter is group created upon installing docker, and you can check that by typing:

```
getent group | grep docker
```

And the second parameter is the user you are adding to the group. The list of users you can check by typing:

```
getent passwd
```

For more information about command `usermod` you can find [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/usermod.8.html).

UPDATED:
I installed docker again and just remembered that when you apply this command you need to restart your machine.

Comment: bizarre. Ditto for me on the reboot. Seems odd

Answer (score 4):

It seems your user cannot use `docker` command, so you need to run it via `sudo` in parentheses as well:

```
sudo docker stop $(sudo docker ps -q)
```

Comment: I thought that if I use the first 'sudo' it would apply for the second command of Docker, new I understood why I was getting this error.